# Dart streams error with .listen().onError().onDone()

Tags: dart

I have an issue with some code that looks like this. In this form I have an error

`The expression here has a type of 'void', and therefore can't be used.
Try checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void.dart(use_of_void_result)`.

If I remove the .onDone() the error goes away. Why? ELI5 please :-)
I was looking at https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-async/Stream/listen.html but seem to still be misundertanding something.
I also read https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-async/StreamSubscription/onDone.html

```
serviceName.UploadThing(uploadRequest).listen((response) {
  uploadMessageOutput = response.message;
  if (response.uploadResult) {
    showSuccess();
  } else {
    showError();
  }
  getUploadFileList(event);

  isSaveInProgress = false;
}).onError((error) {
  isSaveInProgress = false;
  _handleFileUploadError(uploadRequest, error);
}).onDone(() {
  isSaveInProgress = false;
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code is almost right, but will only require a simple change to work correctly.

You would be seeing the same error if you swapped the ordering of `onError` and `onDone`, so the issue has nothing to do with your stream usage. However, you're attempting to chain together calls to `onError` and then `onDone` which won't work since both of these methods return `void`.

What you're looking for is [cascade](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-) notation (`..`), which will allow for you to chain calls to the `StreamSubscription` returned by `listen()`. This is what your code should look like:

```dart
serviceName.UploadThing(uploadRequest).listen((response) {
  uploadMessageOutput = response.message;
  if (response.uploadResult) {
    showSuccess();
  } else {
    showError();
  }
  getUploadFileList(event);

  isSaveInProgress = false;
})..onError((error) { // Cascade
  isSaveInProgress = false;
  _handleFileUploadError(uploadRequest, error);
})..onDone(() {       // Cascade
  isSaveInProgress = false;
});
```